# What happens on the stack during a loop?

Tags: java, stack

When a method is called, the JVM knows how much space to allocate for it.

But if I have a code like this:

```
while(someCondition) {
   Path p = someMethodThatReturnsAPath();
    //do some things
}
```

what is happening on the stack?
Is this what happends?:

- List it creates a pointer on the stack which points to (a pointer that points to the Path returned from the method)
- some stuff is done
- p, or "a pointer to a pointer to a Path object" is removed from the stack
- repeat

Would there be any(even if it's tiny) performance difference between the code above and:

```
Path p = null;
while(someCondition) {
    p = someMethodThatReturnsAPath();
    //do some things
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting about the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you turn Hotspot off then there may be a small performance difference and things will behave pretty much the way that you expect above. With Hotspot engaged then modern JVMs usually use a tiered set of compilers to optimise the code on the fly. Generally the JVM starts interpreted, and then after so many iterations of a method (including loops within the method) then the method will be optimised in a background thread and swapped out at some point with the interpreted version. Then on other triggers more optimisation may occur, or have to be reverted due to new information. You may find that the call to the method in the loop vanishes entirely if the JVM can prove that it does not work and has no side effects, or the loop may get unrolled.

A good way to tell what is going on is to add some JVM flags. The following flags will tell you when a method is being optimised -XX:+PrintCompilation (and is documented here https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/1165804#file_notes.md) and -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly will give you the assembler code that is generated as the C1 and C2 compilers kick in.

Answer (score 0):

All the stack required for a method is allocated on entry to the method and deallocated when leaving it. See the generated bytecode. There is no bytecode instruction corresponding to entering or leaving an inner block. The bytecode for local variables just refers to existing stack slots, by number.

So, the pointer is never 'removed from the stack' at all. The stack slot might get reused by a subsequent declaration outside the scope of the inner block: that's a different thing.

Note that HotSpot doesn't come into it anywhere, contrary to other answers and comments. HotSpot can't optimise instructions that don't exist. (It can *eliminate* code that does exist, however.)

Comment: Just wondering.. Is it any slower though? It has to find a new stack slot for the pointer each loop?